# Does EPSON SDK for Android works with other printers

Tags: sdk, epson

I'm having a POS printer and i'm current;y printing using the ESC/POS commands .The Image has been printed by dividing the image into smaller pixels as byte and printing them byte to byte. My question here is that since EPSON already provides a well defined SDK for android does it work with POS printers other than EPSON since most of them use ESC/POS commands ?

Comment: Could you find an answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to find that out is from the printer manufacturer. I am currently having a similar situation, the specs of the printer say it is compatible with EPSON ESC/POS Commands. So please check the specs.

Comment: Hi, I'm having similar situation, were you able to get your printer print something? Do you know if it's able to be done from any programming environment? I need to do it from Android application